# Elixir-Find second letter of each word

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I need to write a function that accepts a string as a parameter and returns the second letter of each word.

```elixir
ModuleName.function_name("Hello World! This is a test.")
# --> "eohse"
```

I tried it using `Enum` functions but it didn’t work out.

Can anyone find me a solution?

Comment: `"Hello World! This is a test." |> String.split() |> Enum.map(&String.at(&1, 1)) |> Enum.join()` fwiw.

Comment: https://elixirforum.com/t/function-to-return-the-second-letter-of-each-word-in-elixir/50280

Answer (score 2):

You can use [binary pattern matching](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.1/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1-binary-bitstring-matching) combined with a [`for`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.1/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension and [`String.split/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.1/String.html#split/1):

```
for <<_::utf8, x::utf8, _::binary>> <- String.split("Please give me a job"),
    do: <<x::utf8>>,
    into: ""
```

Output:

```
"lieo"
```

Comment: ❤ comprehension ❤

Comment: Also, assuming we deal with a regular language and knowing the longest word is a toponym “Taumatawhakatangi­hangakoauauotamatea­turipukakapikimaunga­horonukupokaiwhen­uakitanatahu,” we might generate 86 clauses of `second_letter(<<…, l::utf8, ?\s>> <> tail), do: second_letter(l, tail)` and use it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly less *gnomically*

```
String.split("Hello World! This is a test.") 
|> Enum.map( fn s-> String.at(s,1) end )    
|> Enum.join()
```

produces

```
"eohse"
```